# jar created by Gradle cant find webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle

I want to build an executable jar that uses selenium. I am trying to do this using shadowJar with the dependencies of selenium and selenium chrome driver.
build.gradle:

```
group 'selenium.test'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar{
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Test'
    }
from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
dependencies {
compile group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '3.6.2'
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.59'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

But when I try to execute the resulting jar I get the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver
>   system property;

Why does this happen despite the indicated chromewebdriver dependency?

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your main method? You are probably not using the webdrivermanager correctly.

Comment: @AndiCover I added it to the question. You mean I have to use System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver","WAY")? But what should I use as the second argument, if it should be in jar, not on computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that you need to set the location of your chromedriver executable as system property. You can do this manually or automated with the library [**io.github.bonigarcia.webdrivermanager**](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) which is already in your dependencies.

---

### WebDriverManager

Add following line to your main method before creating an instance of the ChromeDriver.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This works similar for other drivers as well.

### Manual

The manual method would look like following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```